# How to create childElement from server response in a react app

Tags: html, reactjs, react-dom

I created a react app with many `nested routes`.

One of my nested route is using a backend api that returns a complete `HTML content`.

And I need to display that exact content with same HTML and styling in my UI.

I'm able to successfully achieve it by manipulating the DOM according to axios response using `createElement` and `appendChild` inside `useEffect` method.

But, the whole philosophy behind using react is, to NOT modify the DOM and let react work on it by simly updating the states or props.

My question is:
Is there a cleaner way to use api returned HTML in a react app?

Here is sample relevant code:

**Item.js**

```
...
...
useEffect( ()=>{  
    const fetchAndUpdateItemContent = async () => {
      try {     
        const response = await axios.get(url);
       
        var contentDiv = document.createElement("div");
        contentDiv.innerHTML = response.data.markup;
        document.getElementById(‘itemContent’)
             .appendChild(contentDiv); 
       
      } catch (err) {
          .....
          console.error(err);
          ......
        }
      }
    };
    fetchAndUpdateItemContent(); 
  },[itemId])

  return (
   <div id=‘itemContent'/>
  );
}
```

**What did NOT work**

Ideally I should be able to have a state as `itemContent` in `Item.js` and be able to update it based upon server response like this. But when I do something like below, whole HTML markup is displayed instead of just the displayable content.

```
const [itemContent, setItemContent] = useState(‘Loading ...');

...
    useEffect( ()=>{  
        const fetchAndUpdateItemContent = async () => {
          try {     
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            setItemContent(response.data.markup)  
          } catch (err) {
              .....
              console.error(err);
              ......
            }
          }
        };
        fetchAndUpdateItemContent(); 
      },[itemId])
    
      return (

    <div id=‘itemContent'>
      {itemContent}
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually trying to convert an HTML string to a JSX. You can assign it into react component props called **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**

### Eg:

```
const Item = () => {
  const yourHtmlStringResponse = '<h1>Heading 1</h1><h2>Heading 2</h2>'
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: yourHtmlStringResponse}}></div>
}
```

You can try it here [dangerouslySetInnerHTML-Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-scott-d25dwn?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)